# How do i Modify the append and insert operations in a linked list?

Tags: java

Hello i have an Assignment to modify a java program :

1- Makeing the Append operation be always in the front of the List :

```
LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(5);

myList.append(7);
myList.print();
```

it should be like this :

7 -> 5 -> null

instead of :

5 -> 7 -> null

2- Insert operation will be always as follows: any new added element using insert operation
should be after the current maximum element in the List

```
LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(2);

myList.append(5); 
myList.insert(1);
myList.insert(4);
myList.print();
```

it should be :

5 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> null

instead of :

5 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> null

here is the code

```
class Node {

    Node next;
    int num ;
    public Node(int val) {

        num = val;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class LinkedList {

    Node head;

    public LinkedList(int val) {

        head = new Node(val);
    }

    public void append(int val) {
        Node tmpNode = new Node(val);
        tmpNode.num = val;
        tmpNode.next = head;
        head  = tmpNode;
    } 

    public void insert(int val) {
        Node currentNode = head;
        Node nextNode = head.next;

        if (currentNode.num < val) {

            Node tmpNode = head;
            head = new Node(val);
            head.next = tmpNode;
            return;
        }
        if (nextNode != null && nextNode.num < val) {

            currentNode.next = new Node(val);
            currentNode.next.next = nextNode;
            return;
        }    
        while (nextNode != null && nextNode.num < val) {

            currentNode = nextNode;
            nextNode = nextNode.next;
        }
        currentNode.next = new Node(val);
        currentNode.next.next = nextNode;

    }

    public void delete(int val) {

        Node prevNode = null;

        Node currNode = head;

        if (head.num == val) {

            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        while (currNode != null && currNode.num != val) {

            prevNode = currNode;

            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        if (currNode == null) {

            System.out.println("A node with that value does not exist.");
        } else {

            prevNode.next = currNode.next;
        }
    }

    public void print() {

        Node tmpNode = head;

        while (tmpNode != null) {

            System.out.print(tmpNode.num + " -> ");

            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }

        System.out.print("null" + "\n");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(2);

        myList.append(5); 
        myList.insert(10);
        myList.insert(4);
        myList.print();
    }
}
```

I have tried to do it but i am not sure i did it right

Thanks for your time !

Comment: I recommend writing unit tests to verify your implementation.

Comment: Why not call [`LinkedList::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,E)) ? Pass an index of zero to put the item at the head of the list. No need to alter the meaning of `append`, a word whose literal meaning implies adding on the the rear.

Comment: Why not call [`LinkedList::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,E)) ? Pass an index of zero to put the item at the head of the list. No need to alter the meaning of `append`, a word whose literal meaning implies adding on the the rear. Or is this a school assignment?